# Deploy test agent task runs infinitely and does not exit

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Issue Description:

We have release definitions set up to execute Coded UI test cases, the test agent deployment task has run into an issue where in it the execution does not end until the deployment is manually cancelled, the message displayed on the terminal is as follows "DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'HOSTNAME:5985' is taking time. Please Wait"

vsts_testagent.exe path is supplied from local path.

Environment Details:
TFS on-premises , TFS 2017 15.112.26307.0 (Tfs2017.Update1)

Build Agent : Private, OS: Windows Server 2012 R2, build agent version : 2.112.0

Test Agent : Private, OS: Windows 10

Test deployment task version: vstf_testagent.exe version version 14.0.23107.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test agent deployment step will spend longer time when the first time to deploy the test agents on a machine, if a server has been deployed successfully before, it would be much faster.

Please try below items to fix that:

- Try with same credentials for build agent and test agent.
- Try to download the test agent and install it on that machine manually, then try to queue build with the `test agent deployment task`again. （[Install and configure test agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/lab-management/install-configure-test-agents)）
- Try to deploy the test agent on another clean test machine.

Similar issue in Github for your reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2023

Comment: @Santhosh Have you resolved the issue by above suggestion? any update?

Comment: This issue was resolved after using the same credentials for both build agent and test agent, but this issue has reoccurred, is there any way to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Santhosh Please make sure no one else changed the credentials for build and test agent. double check that and make them the same credentials. Besides, you can try to clean caches for both build and test agent machine, then restart them.

Comment: Test deployment task has been successful and the issue is resolved.